# How to increase annotation font size and bold the annotation value in line chart of google api chart?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I am using google api line chart with annotation. How can I change the font size and font format?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', '');
                    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
                    data.addColumn('number', '');
                    data.addRows([['2010', '67', 67]]);
                    data.addRows([['2011', '69', 69]]);
                    data.addRows([['2012', '68', 68]]);
                    data.addRows([['2013', '67', 67]]);

                    var options = {
                        width: 350,
                        height: 250,
                        pointSize: 5,                           
                        legend: {position: 'none'},
                        chartArea: {
                            left: 0,
                            top: 60,
                            width: 300,
                            height: 75},
                        vAxis: {
                            baselineColor: '#fff',
                            gridlines: {color: '#fff'},
                            minValue: 64,
                            maxValue: 71
                        },
                        tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
                        enableInteractivity: false,
                        annotation: {
                            1: {
                                style: 'default'
                            }
                        },
                        series: {0: {color: '#4D7AD3'}, 1: {color: '#4D7AD3'}}
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            </script>
<body>                
    <h2>Line Charts</h2>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The API does not support styling the annotations.  You can file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support.

Answer (score 29):

Try this

```
var options = {
annotations: {
  textStyle: {
  fontName: 'Times-Roman',
  fontSize: 18,
  bold: true,
  italic: true,
  color: '#871b47',     // The color of the text.
  auraColor: '#d799ae', // The color of the text outline.
  opacity: 0.8          // The transparency of the text.
}
}
};
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Comment: The color option doesn't seem to work. Based on my testing, API automatically chooses the text color based on the color of the background. (light text on dark background or dark text on light background)

Comment: can you post a link or sample code or may be jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks for posting that. To set color I have to specify a style on the bar annotation column itself. What's very confusing is, font properties on that style are ignored- so I had to combine this answer with mine.

Comment: Any way to work position into there? Like top + 10 or something?